# How should I state my affiliation and funding if I am not funded and have no academic affiliation?

Tags: funding, industry, affiliation

I started a project during my math/physics PhD but am now continuing with it from outside of academia, using my own time and funds to purchase resources. What are the conventions for stating my affiliation and funding when writing up this work?

In particular, do I need to/should I name my current (non-research) employer as one of my sources of funding? They have had absolutely nothing to do with this project, other than hiring me to do a different job; they have not endorsed it and should not take any responsibility for it. On the other hand, it is a general principle that funding sources should be disclosed.

Comment: When you say "funding" what do you mean? Are they aware of the project, or are they just paying your salary and don't care what you do in your own time?

Comment: @ObscureOwl Thanks for pointing out the distinction: in my case, the latter. They're aware of the project only to the extent that it was mentioned on my CV.

Comment: In the UK, it's worth noting Section 39(1) of the [Patents Act 1977](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1977/37).

Answer (score 2):

For this project, your "affiliation" is *independent researcher*. Your "funding" is just *self funded*. Both of those are well known and perfectly acceptable.

But be sure that your employer has no claim on your independent work. Some will have a claim, or will claim that they do. For some employers, permission is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If I get you right, you think to mention your employer as a funding source because it pays your salary and you use that to finance your private research? This would not be appropriate. It is up to you what you do with your money and as you state, your employer has nothing to do with your research work.

Because you do your research without an academic affiliation it would be most appropriate to skip this part and do as Buffy suggested. It is furthermore sensible to give an e-mail address which can be used to contact you.